# Creating custom social icons

Tags: css, twitter, icons

I'm new to using AddThis, or any form of social media toolbars etc, however I have the following image:

http://songhype.com/wp-content/themes/song/images/social/twitter.png

I need to code this into a social icon, along with a Facebook version.

My initial idea was to just add that in as an image, and then position the text for the number of followers/tweets to be over the top of the grey portion, however I've found this to not work, is there any other method I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Twitter, you need to get a site key and use their API. Facebook provides a pretty simple copy/paste functionality and has the basic instructions for how to do it on their page.

If you check the HTML for the  you can replace the image with your own.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/follow-button

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/